# Best visualization for gasoline vs performance

Tags: graph

During an interview I was given a question where I had to explain what would be the best graph to use. What was the best way to represent it in terms of visualization, along with what is x and y axis,

Context: Higher price of gasoline brands does not indicate better performance
My Answer: I stated it would be best to use a scatterplot where the x axis is the mileage and the y axis is the price. The only issue is that I feel like I am most likely wrong.

Comment: This question is probably off-topic for Stack Overflow. There's some amount of opinion into what's the best visualization and the questions isn't about how to program such a visualization.

Comment: Also, since this was an interview question there's a good chance that your actual answer wasn't the important part of the question. Instead the interviewer likely wanted to hear your though process, you discussing the trade-offs of different answers, and your explanation and reasoning for picking your answer.